# What to think of $A_{\mathcal{P}}$ in Spec $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have a commutative ring with unity $A$, $f \in A$
and a prine ideal ${\mathcal{P}}$. I have learned that
$A_f$ can be naturally thought of as an open subset of Spec $A$.
I was wondering if something similar holds for the localized (at ${\mathcal{P}}$) ring
$A_{\mathcal{P}}$? (i.e. can we naturally view $A_{\mathcal{P}}$ as an open subset of Spec $A$?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $A_f$ is the ring of global sections of the standard-open subset $D(f)$ with respect to the usual sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)}$ on $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$. You have to distinguish between $A_f$ and $D(f)$. The connection is given by $D(f) \cong \mathrm{Spec}(A_f)$ and $A_f \cong \Gamma(D(f),\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)})$.
- $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is the [stalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalk_%28sheaf%29) of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)}$ at $\mathfrak{p}$. Thus, this ring captures the local information at $\mathfrak{p}$.

(This is explained in detail in every introduction to affine schemes, for example the book by Görtz-Wedhorn or by Bosch.)